# Not Equals en la clausula Where

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo las siguientes tablas

```
create table Puesto
(
    id_puesto int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    piso int,
    cantidad_sillas int,
    frente_ventana bit,
    cantidad_computadoras int,
    cantidad_sillas_adicionales int,
    acceso_sala_reuniones bit
)

create table Alquiler
(
    id_alquiler int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    id_puesto int,
    foreign key (id_puesto) references Puesto (id_puesto),
    dni_cliente int,
    foreign key (dni_cliente) references Cliente (dni),
    precio money,
    adicion_ventana money,
    adicion_computadoras money,
    adicion_acceso_tiempolibre money,
    adiccion_sillas money
)
```

Y necesito obtener todos aquellos puestos que no están en alquiler. Para lo siguiente deduzco que no tengo que mostrar todos aquellos Puestos cuya id_puesto sea igual a la id_puesto de mi tabla Alquiler. Tengo el siguiente código pero no me arroja los resultados deseados.

```
SELECT Puesto.piso, Puesto.cantidad_sillas, Puesto.frente_ventana, Puesto.id_puesto, Alquiler.id_puesto
FROM Puesto, Alquiler
WHERE Puesto.id_puesto != Alquiler.id_puesto
```

He probado usando también **<>** en vez de **!=** pero los resultados son los mismos.

Comment: Intenta cambiar el select, a `FROM Puesto INNER JOIN Alquiler on Alquiler.id_puesto = Puesto.id_puesto WHERE Alquiler.puesto IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, si intentas mostrar todos los puestos que no estan en alquiler, puedes hacer un `Left OUTER Join` y mostrar los que su ID sea null:

```
SELECT Puesto.piso, Puesto.cantidad_sillas, Puesto.frente_ventana, Puesto.id_puesto, Alquiler.id_puesto
FROM Puesto LEFT OUTER JOIN Alquiler ON Puesto.id_puesto = Alquiler.id_puesto 
WHERE Alquiler.id_alquiler IS NULL
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me sirvió.